# mysql_connect host service

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello all, i have just uploaded my site to server and i am having some problems in connecting to database. previously i was working on local server and i used the following codes

```
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('fetwork.com',$connection);     
?>
```

but now i have uploaded my site to `justhost.com` and everything is changed like database name server,username etc.

can anyone tell me how to replace the previous code to the new code please .

i know my database name `multiima_database` but dont know the `username` and `password` do i have to put FTP username,password or host there ?

Comment: host panel site usually gives you right to create database user and provide username and password you create in connection.

Comment: Sorry but this is like asking us what's the PIN of your credit card.

Comment: try to switch from mysql to mysqli and if you do not remember db username / password, try creating a new one from the cpanel and use that info in your file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming, but webhost configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Export your SQL file from the localhost database
2. Visit your host's control panel and choose 'phpMyAdmin'
3. Import your SQL file there
4. Return to your host's control panel
5. Set the username and password again there under(database manager) (you can do them the same)

If you just beginning, please move to using either MySQLI or PDO, as mysql is already deprecated.